# What free screen design tools are available

Tags: screen

I am looking for a free tool to quickly create a screen design in a workshop with a customer (for a web application).

The focus of the tool should be on a functional definition of screens and not on the design of them.

Do you have any suggestions for an appropriate tool?

Comment: what about opening up the question a little to tools suitable for any kind of wireframing - thick/smart client as well as web?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found [mockupscreens](http://mockupscreens.com/) to be pretty good. The designs look exactly like works in progress and keeps clients from getting distracted

Answer (score 5):

[Balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/)

- Online
- Quick and easy to use
- Drawings have a hand drawn feel so you can avoid design details and focus on layout and function
- You can save (XML) your drawing to open up later
- Can save as drawing an image

Comment: Balsamiq isn't free. After 7 days you will need to buy a copy or you won't be able to save your designs. If you can afford it then it's well worth it.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It was free for-ever when I posted, just had some pop-up messages. Still free for 7 days might be enough for some purposes.

Comment: is it also the official tool used in ux.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

[Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn/) is pretty good:

> Pencil is built for the purpose of providing a free and open-source GUI prototyping tool that people can easily install and use to create mockups in popular desktop platforms.

Comment: The link in the answer is broken. The current Pencil link is here: http://pencil.evolus.vn/

Answer (score 2):

Balsamiq's Mockups worked very well for us.  The product actually delivered more than it promised.  Everyone to whom we showed our Mockups wanted to know about the development tool we used.  Even though, as another commenter observed, the Mockups intentionally look like works in progress, the functionality of our Mockups was such that those to whom they were showed started confusing the Mockups with functioning software--we had to keep on reminded people that the Mockups are only sophisticated specifications.  Additionally, the Balsamiq folks who make the product are some of the nicest people with whom I've ever worked.  Though the retail price of the product is not free (sometimes free is not really economical), its cost is very reasonable and it will more than pay for itself by producing a solid, semi-functional, easily modified prototype very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Any WYSIWYG tool should do the job. I would recommend something like [Kompozer](http://www.kompozer.net) to get the initial job done, providing you are not too worried about design, and will therefore start more or less from scratch with the actual product.

Answer (score 0):

I find that using a PowerPoint like app can do wonders.  You design different aspects and make new slides.  Use the notes to record details.  [Google Presentations](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/topic.py?topic=15116&hl=en_US) is free and would be fine for what you want.

For some money there is http://www.axure.com/ which is a much more robust "prototyping" tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out video http://malaysia.video.yahoo.com/watch/919824/3643540 about paper prototyping :)